# Cron Expression to Run job on every 8th Day

Tags: quartz-scheduler, hangfire

I recently integrated Hangfire in my project and it is working fine. I am having some long running jobs that are actually taking 4-5 days to complete, So what I am trying to do is to Run these jobs on every 8th day means if it triggers on 1st Feb then 9th Feb then 17 Feb like this.

Can any one **help me in creating the Cron Expression** for this, as CronExpressionBuilder class doesn't have such function to create Cron Expression.

Comment: Himanshu, do you really have to use a CronTrigger? For these types of schedules you will be better off using a CalendarIntervalTrigger. CIT will take care of months transitions etc. You will set the start time = Feb 1, repeat interval unit = DAY, repeat interval = 8 and that is it.

Answer (score 1):

Issue Resolved.

I changed my apporach and using below mentioned cron expression..

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.Write("Recurring"), "0 10 */8 * *");
```

And is working like a charm.